# Facing very weird issue of out of memory on Android Studio even after setting up higher memory

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

Since last few days, I am getting following error in Android Studio when opens up more than 5-7 files in editor or try to open other reference project parallel. It starts giving me alert as like below. Event I have updated its vmoptions setting to 4GB and also increased other required memory too.

[image: Out of memory error alert screen]

Android Studio version:

[image: About Android Studio]

Here, studio.vmoptions file content:

```
#-Xms1024m
#-Xmx4096m
#-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
#-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
#-XX:+UseCompressedOops

// NEW FILE CONTENT
-Xmx4096m
-Xms2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-da

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_studio.hprof

# ###############################################
# custom settings from https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/AndroidStudio-VM-Options/blob/master/studio.vmoptions
# ###############################################

# Runs JVM in Server mode with more optimizations and resources usage
# It may slow down the startup, but if you usually keep IDE running for few hours/days
# JVM may profile and optimize IDE better. Feel free to remove this flag.
-server

# Sets the initial size of the heap, default value is 256m
-Xms2G

# Max size of the memory allocation pool, default value is 1280m
-Xmx4G

# Sets the size of the allocated class metadata space that will trigger a GC the first time it is exceeded, default max value is 350m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=1024m
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

I am not sure what changed after updating Android SDK and Android Studio to 4.2.1. But I feel frustrating due to frequently occur this error. Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Have you changed the JDK IDE runs under https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html ? Make sure you are running AS under the bundled JBR runtime.